# Angular - How to get objects in a nested array of objects

Tags: angular

In Angular-14 application, I have this JSON response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pageItems": [
      {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "merchantId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "userId": "string",
        "merchant": {
          "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
          "merchantName": "string",
          "accountNumber": "string",
          "userLists": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "firstName": "string",
              "lastName": "string",
              "email": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  "successful": true,
  "message": "string",
  "statusCode": 0
}
```

Then I represented it model interface as shown below:

merchant-user-list.model:

```
export interface IUserList {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
}

export interface IMerchant {
  id: string;
  merchantName: string;
  accountNumber: string;
}

export interface IPageItem {
  id: string;
  merchantId: string;
  userId: string;
  merchant: IMerchant;
}

export interface IData {
  pageItems: IPageItem[];
}

export interface IMerchantUserList {
  data: IData;
  successful: boolean;
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
}
```

However, I want to search the DB table using firstName, lastName and email. So I did this in the typescript component.

merchant-users-list.component:

```
import { MerchantUserService } from 'src/app/services/merchant-user.service';
import { IData, IPageItem, IMerchantUserList } from 'src/app/models/merchant/merchant-user-list.model';

export class MerchantUsersComponent implements OnInit {
  allMerchantUserList: any[] = [];
  dataBk: IPageItem[] = this.allMerchantUserList;

  constructor(
    private merchantService: MerchantUserService
  ) {
  }

  onMerchantUserSearch() {
    this.allMerchantUserList = this.dataBk.filter(
      (row) =>
        row.merchant.userLists[0].firstName
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.selectedName?.toLowerCase()) && row.merchant.userLists[0].lastName
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.selectedName?.toLowerCase()) && row.merchant.userLists[0].email
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.selectedName?.toLowerCase())
    );
  }
}
```

I want to filter (search) all the objects in the nested array using firstName, lastName and email in textboxes.

What I have above will only get the objects of length 0. When I did row.merchant.userLists.firstName, I got an error that firstName, lastName and email are not available in userLists.

How do I re-write onMerchantUserSearch() to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Think that `IMerchant` was wrong. Missing `userLists: IUserList[]` property. You probably will get error: "userLists doesn't existed in merchant".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st issue**

Based on your existing interface, probably you will get the error:

> userLists property doesn't exist in merchant

as you miss out

```js
userLists: IUserList[];
```

property in the `IMerchant` interface.

**2nd issue**

As the `userLists` is an array, you can't directly access the class property but you have to iterate each item in the array.

Via `.find()`, it will return a value if found and return `null` if not found. The `.filter()` will query the item in which the predicate (result) is neither `null`, `undefined` nor `false`.

```js
this.allMerchantUserList = this.dataBk.filter((row) =>
  row.merchant.userLists.find(
    (x) =>
      x.firstName
        ?.toLowerCase()
        .includes(this.selectedName?.toLowerCase()) &&
      x.lastName
        ?.toLowerCase()
        .includes(this.selectedName?.toLowerCase()) &&
      x.email?.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedName?.toLowerCase())
  )
);
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tc6kkn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)